# when building an iPhone or android app using flutter and dart, how can you see http response cookies returned in the header of http requests?

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, cookies

When visiting a website using any modern web browser (like Chrome), you can view the Cookies that are transmitted as shown below:

[image]

As an example, the above picture is for amazon.com, and in Chrome you can right click on Inspect >> Application >> and look at Cookies drop down for all the cookies transmitted by amazon.com.

When writing a mobile application using [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) and [Dart](https://dart.dev/multiplatform-apps) for iPhone/Android, how does one do the same thing shown above in the picture (i.e. how do you know which cookies have been transmitted by the server just like we can see them in Chrome's Inspect >> Application ?) ?

Comment: the answer linked does not address my question.  I'm looking for a way to see what cookies are stored in the mobile app without modifying any code.

Comment: That's easy to answer - you cannot. Firstly, what's to say that the mobile app even parses the cookie header. Then as to how or whether it stores them (encrypted or not? etc) can only be known by the app developer.